# Magento 1.9 Admin notification bar display 502 bad gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, adminnotification

My Magento 1.9 admin suddenly show a 502 bad gateway message. What is wrong? It says nginx, but my Magento is running on Apache server.

I do have a nginx server running besides Apache. But the message still displays even if I stop the nginx service.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the link doesn't solve my problem. I'm not even using nginx. my magento is running on apache2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Nitrogento extensions then it could be because of them.
Seems like their servers are offline, and extension returning 502 Bad Gateway

http://www.nitrogento.com/

Comment: you are completely right. It is because of Nitrogento. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Greate dude.. ;)